# Primes of Atlantis: a definition and a problem

Tags: sequences-and-series, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, ceiling-and-floor-functions

We denote the floor function as $\lfloor x\rfloor$, and for integers $k\geq 1$ we consider the following sum of the areas of three consecutive circles $$\pi  k^2+\pi(k+1)^2+\pi(k+2)^2=\pi  \left( 3k^2+6k+5\right). $$

> **Definition.** When for an integer $n\geq 1$ the integer 
>   $$\mathcal{A}(n)=\lfloor  \pi\left( 3n^2+6n+5\right) \rfloor$$ is a prime number, I say that it's a prime of Atlantis.

Our sequence of prime of Atlantis starts as $$43, 157, 241, 769, 4567, 11551, 14341, 16631, 19949\ldots$$ corresponding to the indexes $n's:1, 3, 4, 8, 21, 34, 38, 41, 45, \ldots$ as you can see with these codes using [Wolfram Alpha online calculator:](https://www.wolframalpha.com)

`Table IsPrime(floor(pi (n^2+(n+1)^2+(n+2)^2))), for n=1 to 100`

`Table floor(pi (n^2+(n+1)^2+(n+2)^2)), for n=1 to 100`

> **Question.** I would like to know if we can deduce if there are infinitely many primes of Atlantis. **Many thanks.**

If you can't solve the problem, but you can provide us useful reasonings or calculations about the Question, please share your knowledges.

Comment: Many thanks for your attention. Now I don't understand well your question. I don't know if your question is related with my calculations. On the other hand notice that I am a bad programmer @Peter  When I wrote my previous codes that I evoke is that one can do a comparison of both tables.

Comment: For $n=10^{100}+142$, we get a large "prime of Atlantis". There should be infinite many, but proves that a sequence contains infinite many primes , in particular if irrational numbers and floor functions are involved, are usually out of reach.

Comment: What I mean : You used Wolfram Alpha and apparently got only the array with the integers. What was your exact input ?

Comment: About your opinion I am agree since this kind of problems are (miscellaneous) difficult to solve. I did this question to try some useful reasoning (see my last paragraph). On the other hand your prime $10^{100}+142$ sems fantastic and ...is the largest number known, so far! Many thanks for share it @Peter

Comment: If you want larger examples , I can calculate them for you. Or if you download PARI/GP (if you do not have it already) , I can give you the code to find large examples for yourself.

Comment: You are a pioneer calculating the highest primes of Atlantis known, now also Peter's primes. If you want to add a table or a graph of the associated counting function do it. Many thanks @Peter

Comment: The number-theoretic tools available are almost certainly not enough to solve this question. We don't even know the answer to a seemingly (slightly) simpler problem - whether there are infinitely primes of the form $n^2+1$. Throwing transcendental number into the problem is probably not going to make it simpler...

Comment: I accept your critics. Truly my problem was a little joke about the three circles of the Atlantis and the floor function. But I thought that maybe some user using theorems as Bertrand's postulate, the definiton of the floor function, or formulas/recurrences involving $\pi$ could say something about the question. Many thanks for your attention @Wojowu , and help from Peter.

Answer (score 3):

This is not a complete answer , but I show some statistics about the "primes of Atlantis"

Program PARI/GP is used

First of all the $n$ upto $1000$, for which we get a "prime of Atlantis" :

```
\p 10000 { High precision calculation }
pa(n)=isprime(truncate(Pi*(3*n^2+6*n+5)),2)==1 {pa(n) is true if and only if we get a prime of Atlantis by choosing $n$}

? select(m->pa(m)==1,[0..1000])
%4 = [1, 3, 4, 8, 21, 34, 38, 41, 45, 69, 75, 91, 136, 166, 179, 190, 202, 222,
227, 228, 229, 230, 239, 267, 284, 308, 313, 317, 323, 351, 359, 381, 392, 409,
417, 429, 433, 434, 442, 449, 456, 460, 463, 468, 486, 490, 518, 527, 549, 585,
588, 607, 632, 651, 668, 670, 684, 694, 700, 703, 727, 764, 775, 782, 805, 811,
814, 820, 821, 844, 850, 894, 896, 920, 925, 926, 932, 969, 979, 985]
?
```

For $n\in [1,10]$ , we get $4$ primes

For $n\in [10,100]$ , we get $8$ primes

For $n\in [100,1000]$ , we get $68$ primes

For $n\in [10^3,10^4]$ , we get $498$ primes

For $n\in [10^4,10^5]$ , we get $3778$ primes

For $n\in [10^5,10^6]$ , we get $31767$ primes

Some large $n$, for which we get a "prime of Atlantis"

$$10^{100}+142$$ $$10^{200}+114$$ $$10^{500}+6391$$ $$10^{1000}+1395$$

with $201$ , $401$ , $1001$ and $2001$ digits respectively. There are probably infinite many "primes of Atlantis", but it is hard to imagine that this can be proven.

Comment: Now without jokes in my words: your work is incredible, thank you very much for your statistics and conjecture. A vote up, and if I could, I should vote your answer 101 times.

Comment: @user243301 Thank you, at least you can accept it ...